# SimpleHTMLDOM не работает

Tags: php, yii, парсер

Есть результат работы curl `$html_2` (возвращает результат поиска запчастей по номеру, которые нужно спарсить, все работает нормально).

При поиске одних номеров `SimpleHTMLDOM` работает и все парсится, при других выдает пустой результат `$div`, хотя структура контента на входе везде одинаковая.

В чем проблема?

```
if (!empty($html_2)) {
        Yii::import('ext.SimpleHTMLDOM.SimpleHTMLDOM');
        $simpleHTML = new SimpleHTMLDOM;
        $div = $simpleHTML->str_get_html($html_2);
}
```

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9QbQWpbZX1YMUdYeEZCQkMyYk0/view?usp=sharing-здесь](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9QbQWpbZX1YMUdYeEZCQkMyYk0/view?usp=sharing-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C) весь код полностью.

Comment: добавьте в теги название языка программировани.

Comment: @Roma Tulaydan От вас нужна полная информация: **какой Урл** вы парсите, **ПОЛНЫЙ** код какой используете, **НА КАКИХ КОНКРЕТНО** местах происходит пустота, а на каких всё нормально, и прочее

Comment: Я немного разобрался в ситуации,теперрь при запросе некоторых номеров выдает следущее:file_get_contents(http://sklep.martex-rybnik.pl/../Handlers/ArticleDocument.ashx?fileId=FC874AE94FC46E8729A348385381B5BF4065DDB7A3CA46F574558C418A3A9A0D561CE407A37F95C5D033B12178BA0EA45A6BB24FC0B576902BE24A4E12FB4380): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden .Что може тбыть причиной такой ошибки?Другие запросы идут нормально. Спасибо.

Comment: @RomaTulaydan  без подробной информации, ЧТО вы делаете, КАК вы делаете,  ЧТО  ПАРСИТЕ, и прочей вам никто не поможет и гадать на кофейной гуще не будет..... Причина может быть любой из многих

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9QbQWpbZX1YMUdYeEZCQkMyYk0/view?usp=sharing-здесь веськод полностью.